# HTML form with input radio and one text input with the same attribute name

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am trying to do a radio buttons group with couple of options and the last option will be a text input field "Other".
Something like this:

[image]

I want to do it so when submitted, the url called is

> app://configuration?server=...

server should contain the value of the server attribute wether it's from one of the radio buttons or from the input group

I tried to do this

```
<form method="GET" action="app://configuration">
  Select server <br>
  <input type="radio" name="server" value="1">Production<br>
  <input type="radio" name="server" value="2">Test<br>
  <input type="radio" name="server" value="3">Localhost<br>
  <input type="radio" name="server" value="">Other <input type="text" name="server" />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

I have used the same `name` attribute for the radio buttons and the input field and the result  is that the `name` (server) is being duplicated when the submit is pressed.

I understand why it doesn't work in the current way. Any idea how to achieve something like this with javascript ? (no third party like jquery please)

**I have no access to change the server code so I can't use a different attribute name because the server will not know it...**

Comment: Of course, if you use another input with the same name you will receive 2 entries. You have to change the name of the text input.

Comment: @christof13 That's what I am trying to avoid

Comment: You can use a hidden field named server and fill it with the correct value before the submit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this pure javascript (modified your html code)

```js
function changeradioother() {
  var other = document.getElementById("other");
  other.value = document.getElementById("inputother").value;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="server" value="1">Production<br>
<input type="radio" name="server" value="2">Test<br>
<input type="radio" name="server" value="3">Localhost<br>
<input type="radio" name="server" id="other" value="other">Other <input id="inputother" type="text" onchange="changeradioother()" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

I added an id to the last radio button and the inputbox.

Answer (score 3):

You cant use the same name for the text input. Radio buttons are fine because only one will be returned to the server.

```
Other <input type="text" name="serverCustom" />
```

Check to see if the value of "server" is null or empty ("") when you get it, and then if it is grab the value of serverCustom.

If you wish to use pure javascript to check the values, and send the data you require use this:

http://jsfiddle.net/Lord_Zero/w5x4h/

Comment: You do not control the server that you are sending this data to? You will have to use JQuery to intercept the form submit event, check the server value, if its "" then do a $.post and send the textbox value as the payload. If you cant use Jquery use Javascript to do what I explained above and then use this to send your post http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp

Comment: I edited my answer with a jsfiddle that uses pure javascript to comb through all your radio buttons, and send a get request. If it finds a selected radio button with "" then it will check the value of the textbox and send that. You can improve my code by adding an alert() if there are no checked radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to do?

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/g4yMA/1/)

```
 function submit(){
var curRadio = document.querySelector('input[name="server"]:checked').value;
    var serverValue;
    if(curRadio==4)
    {
        serverValue=document.getElementById("other").value;
    }
    else
    {
        serverValue=curRadio;
    }
    alert(serverValue);
}
```